# Perfoming Vim substitue on a partial line

Tags: editor, vim

we can perform vim substitute on a set of lines by selecting them in visual mode and entering command mode. it auto populates the selected range
:'<,'>

and we can perform substitute like
:'<,'>s/TestSubstitute//gc

I would like to know is it possible in vim to perform substitute command on a partial line selected in visual mode, so something like

> :`<,``> [followed by substitute
>   command]

Generally,i will copy a set of field names separated by delimeter "," in vim and would like to calculate the column count which can be determined by the number of comma occurrences once all the field names are selected in visual mode.

select fname,lastmodtime,lastaccesstime from fileInfo;

If i select the text from fname to lastaccesstime in visual mode and would like to know the number of commas in the selected text.

Thanks in advance,
Naga Kiran

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\%V` modifier in pattern expression.  It will force vim to match only within visual block you're currently in or were in before.  Use the modifier like this:

```
:s/\%Vpattern/substitution/
```

In visual mode this will be shown as:.

```
:'<,'>s/\%Vpattern/substitution/
```

Comment: That partially worked for me.  I tried selecting the text within parentheses comprising a comma-separated pair of arguments, and then tried to swap them using ":'<,'>s/\%V\(.*\), \(.*\)/\1, \2". It did start at the beginning of the visual selection, but then operated on the text from there to the end of the line, not just to the end of the selection on the line.  After the substitution, the highlight had been extended to the end of the line.